# Can you use AdminBro as admin panel with MySQL and express.js?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, admin

Can you use AdminBro as an admin panel with MySQL and express.js without having to use sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use either sequelize or typeorm (supported adapters). Otherwise, you would need to create your own adapter which connects with MySQL directly.